# How to show django messages based on queryset filter?

Tags: python, django

I want to show message based on my filter.

```
CHOICES = (

        ('0', 'published',),

        ('1', 'pending',),

        ('2', 'rejected',),

        )
```

Here I tried this code for showing message based on filter but it’s only showing the published message.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

            data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

            published = BlogComment.objects.filter(is_published="0")

            pending = BlogComment.objects.filter(is_published="1")

            

            if published:

                 messages.add_message(self.request, messages.INFO, 'Comment status published Sucessfully')

            elif pending: 

               messages.add_message(self.request, messages.INFO, 'Comment status pending Sucessfully')

            

            return data
```

why I am only getting the published message?

I also tried if statement instead of elif. After using if statement I am getting three message at time while changing status of any object.

```
        if published:
             messages.add_message(self.request, messages.INFO, 'Comment Published Sucessfully')
        if pending: 
             messages.add_message(self.request, messages.INFO, 'Comment Status Pending')
        if rejected:
             messages.add_message(self.request, messages.INFO, 'Comment Status
```

Comment: Well because you have used `elif` meaning it will run only if the previous `if` (or `elif`) condition was not met... Try `if pending:` instead.

Comment: Thanks  Abdul Aziz Barkat it worked.

Comment: Abdul Aziz Barkat  it's worked but getting notification for all published object, Pending object. Where I am editing only one object

Comment: Abdul Aziz getting two message at a time  after edit

Comment: That is a _different_ question. The problem though is quite obvious you are filtering the model to find those objects `BlogComment.objects.filter(is_published="0")` so you should be getting _all_ of those matching instances.

Comment: Abdul Aziz Barkat  I updated my question. How to stop showing extra message. Such as if I change status published then it should be show message only  only for published

Comment: I also tried to use pk in filter but didn't work `BlogComment.objects.filter(is_published="0", pk=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to display the status update of a single object? If so then you can simply update your view logic where view is inherited from `from django.views.generic import UpdateView`.

```
from django.views.generic import UpdateView
from django.contrib import messages


class YourUpdateView(UpdateView):
    # other part of view 
   
    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save()
        status = self.object.status
        messages.success(self.request, f"Status updated to {status}")
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

If I'm mistaken please explain in detail in the comment.